# How to get values back from service?

Tags: android, android-service

I am writing an application in which i have two Activities and one service.
Now i want to get some values from service through main activity and send that values to second activity. Basically i want to get a string array back from service and send that array in to next activity. I know i can send that sring array to next activity by the help of Intent.putextra(). 
But i don't how to get string array from service which is running in background. Please help me..
Thankx..

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.mamlambo.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Update UI, new "message" processed by SimpleIntentService

       String text = (String)intent.getStringExtra(Login.PARAM_OUT_MSG);
    }
 }
```

Comment: probably should mention the source material http://android10.org/index.php/articleswhitepapers/314-android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics